# Intermediate value theorem 2

Tags: real-analysis

If   $ \ y'=y \ g(x,y) $ and suppose that $ \ g \ \ and \ \ \partial g / \partial x $  are defined and continuous for all x,y . Then show that $ \ y(x)=0 $ is a unique solution . **(Use Intermediate value theorem)**  $$ $$  I can prove the uniqueness of the solution but i can't show how $ y(x)=0$  is a solution. Please someone help me

Comment: It's pretty obvious $y=0$ is solution. How did you prove the uniqueness?

Comment: i have tried to show that y' >0   or y'< 0 , the y(x) is strictly monotone and hence by intermediate theorem y=0 is unique

Comment: Replace $y(x)$ in the RHS of the equation and see what happens with $y'$.

Comment: then  what is the use of  g and g(x,y) ?